# When to handle services in the msi installer InstallExecuteSequence table

Tags: windows-installer

I want to write a transform (.mst) file to an existing installer (.msi) file in order to correctly manage a service that is part of the installation. That is, the executable of the service is part of the msi, but the msi is not "aware" that this is a service. The predefined InstallExecuteSequence runs like this:

```
Action                  Condition         Sequence
...
InstallValidate         <null>            1400
RemoveExistingProducts  AI_UPGRADE<>"NO"  1450
InstallInitialize       <null>            1500
...
StopServices            VersionNT         1900
DeleteServices          VersionNT         2000
...
RemoveFiles             <null>            3500
...
InstallFiles            <null>            4000
...
InstallServices         VersionNT         5800
StartServices           VersionNT         5850
...
InstallFinalize         <null>            6600
```

The first thing I needed to do in my MST was to add suitable entries to the (initially empty or not even included) tables `ServiceControl` and `ServiceInstall`. So far, so good.
However, I am now having doubts about the InstallExecuteSequence, and whether I ought to push around the positions of the four service-related actions:

The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/removeexistingproducts-action) has this to say about `RemoveExistingProducts`  as used above:

> In this case, the installer removes the old applications entirely before installing the new applications. This is an inefficient placement for the action because all reused files have to be recopied.

This has me somewhat confused. Isn't the deleting and copying of files (reused or not) done in the `RemoveFiles` and `InstallFiles` (and perhaps a few related) actions? 
Somehow the quote above seems to suggest that (in case of an upgrade) the old version of my service exe file will be replaced with its new version before the service gets stopped (and even before `InstalInitialize` begins the installation transaction?!?)
Does that mean I should consider relocating the `RemoveExistingProducts`  action in my MST? Or relocating the Stop/Delete services actions before `RemoveExistingProducts` and  accordingly the Install/start service actions after the end of the installation transaction, i.e., after `InstallFinalize`? This does not seem right either - of course these actions shoul dbe guarded by the transaction (in particular in cases where the transaction has to be rolled back during a first install or a complete uninstall).

My gut feeling is that I shouldnÄt worry and everything is fine in the sequence as-is, and I am just misunderstanding something. So I'd be thankful if someone could enlighten me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will be a little rushed, will look back later - no QA done:

---

> ***Uninstall***: **`RemoveExistingProducts`** actually kicks of the **`InstallExecuteSequence`** of the existing installation for your product - to uninstall it as part of the **major upgrade** process you
>   are running. So "inside" **`RemoveExistingProducts`** the whole
>   uninstall of the old version of your product takes place. Within the
>   other version's **`InstallExecuteSequence`** the actual
>   file-operations are done by **`RemoveFiles`** as you suspect, then
>   control returns to the original location in your new MSI. Like a
>   function call in other words - it returns to where the uninstall was
>   invoked.

***Service***: I would keep the sequencing you show in your question.

- **`StartServices`** and **`InstallServices`** should happen after **`RemoveFiles`** and **`InstallFiles`**
- **`StopServices`** and **`DeleteServices`** should happen before **`InstallFiles`** and **`InstallServices`**.

***RemoveExistingProduct Placement***: If you change the placement of **`RemoveExistingProducts`** you will switch between different sequencing options for major upgrade uninstall and reinstall behavior:

- ***Early REP***: Uninstalling the old version fully, then invoking the new installation to complete the product upgrade. This is forgiving of component reference errors and frequently used.
- ***Late REP***: Your new product is installed overwriting all upgraded files, and then obsolete files are removed and removed registry settings etc... This yields an upgrade that effectively installs like a patch. It is very vulnerable to component referencing errors and is often abandoned if you do not know 100% what you can and can not do.

***Major Upgrade***: There are several flavors of the above two overall sequencing options, and [**the WiX documentation lists them here**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html). It is the **`Schedule`** attribute. There are many options - each with important quirks and factors: **`afterInstallValidate`**, **`afterInstallInitialize`**, **`afterInstallExecute`**, **`afterInstallExecuteAgain`**, **`afterInstallFinalize`**. *Please read the linked documentation thoroughly*.